# Mapping 2 String fields to OffsetDateTime with MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have the following DTO which has 2 fields that must be converted to OffsetDateTime:

```
@Data
public class AppointmentDTO {

    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String startTime;

    @NotNull
    private String endTime;

    @NotNull
    private String timeZoneStart;

    @NotNull
    private String timeZoneEnd;

    // other fields
}
```

to

```
@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String timeZoneStart;
    private String timeZoneEnd;
    private OffsetDateTime startTime;
    private OffsetDateTime endTime;
    private OffsetDateTime createdTime;
    // other fields
}
```

In order to convert, I need the DTO's `timeZone` fields plus a `DateTimeFormatter`. So, my attempt is this:

```
@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface IAppointmentMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdTime", ignore = true)
    Appointment convertAppointmentDTOToAppointment(AppointmentDTO dto, @Context OffsetDateTimeMapper offsetDateTimeMapper);
}
```

```
public class OffsetDateTimeMapper {

    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private String timeZoneStart;
    private String timeZoneEnd;
    private final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter;

    public OffsetDateTimeMapper(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {
        this.dateTimeFormatter = dateTimeFormatter;
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void beforeStartTimeMapping(AppointmentDTO dto) {
        this.startTime = dto.getStartTime();
        this.timeZoneStart = dto.getTimeZoneStart();
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void beforeEndTimeMapping(AppointmentDTO dto) {
        this.endTime = dto.getEndTime();
        this.timeZoneEnd = dto.getTimeZoneEnd();
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void startTimeMap(@MappingTarget Appointment appointment) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime, dateTimeFormatter);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZoneStart));
        appointment.setStartTime(zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime());
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void endTimeMap(@MappingTarget Appointment appointment) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endTime, dateTimeFormatter);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZoneEnd));
        appointment.setEndTime(zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime());
    }
}
```

When I build, however, I get the following error: `Error:(22,17) java: Can't map property "java.lang.String startTime" to "java.time.OffsetDateTime startTime". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.time.OffsetDateTime map(java.lang.String value)".` If I put a `default map()` method on the interface, I don't get the error, but I don't have the proper `@Context` required.

```
/*default OffsetDateTime map(String value) {
     LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value);
     ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
     return zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();
}*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is interesting. In order to work properly you would have to explicitly ignore the properties that you don't want MapStruct to automatically map.

In this case add:

```
@Mapping(target = "startTime", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "endTime", ignore = true)
```

However, in your case I would try to use [Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) and use the source parameters as source.

So something like:

```
@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface IAppointmentMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdTime", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "startTime", source = "dto", qualifiedByName = "startTime")
    @Mapping(target = "endTime", source = "dto", qualifiedByName = "endTime")
    Appointment convertAppointmentDTOToAppointment(AppointmentDTO dto, @Context DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter);

    @Named("startTime")
    default OffsetDateTime mapStartTime(AppointmentDTO dto, @Context DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dto.getStartTime(), dateTimeFormatter); 
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(dto. getTimeZoneStart()));
        return zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime()
    }

    @Named("endTime")
    default OffsetDateTime mapEndTime(AppointmentDTO dto, @Context DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dto.getEndTime(), dateTimeFormatter); 
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(dto. getTimeZoneEnd()));
        return zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime()
    }
}
```

Note: `@Named` is `org.mapstruct.Named`.